# Can't set "max connections" - parameter of memcached higher than 4096 (exited status 71)

Tags: linux, memcached

My start parameter for memcached are:

```
-m 900 -p 11211 -t 5 -l 127.0.0.1 -r 200000 -c 4096
```

If "-c" (max connections) is more than 4096, memcached won't start.

> memcached.service - memcached daemon
>   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled)
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-10-13 13:25:15 CEST; 17s ago
>   Process: 17667 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/memcached $MEMCACHED_PARAMS (code=exited, status=71)
>   Main PID: 17667 (code=exited, status=71)
>
> Oct 13 13:25:15 openSUSE-131-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting memcached daemon...
>   Oct 13 13:25:15 openSUSE-131-64-minimal systemd[1]: Started memcached daemon.
>   Oct 13 13:25:15 openSUSE-131-64-minimal systemd[1]: memcached.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=71/n/a
>   Oct 13 13:25:15 openSUSE-131-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit memcached.service entered failed state.

Does someone know what could cause these problem?

Comment: Perhaps your `ulimit -n` is too low (number of open file handles)? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-rhel-centos-memcache-failedto-setrlimit/

Comment: Thanks, but sadly no. ulimit -n is set to 120000.